# RuntimeException with Nutch User interface

Tags: user-interface, web-crawler, nutch

Started NutchUiServer and after connecting to http://localhost:8080/ i get: 
Unexpected RuntimeException

```
Last cause: Unable to find property: 'navbar.menu.dashboard' for component:[class=org.apache.nutch.webui.pages.DashboardPage]. Locale: null, style: null
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public org.apache.nutch.webui.pages.DashboardPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
```

**Stacktrace Root cause:**

java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Unable to find property: 'navbar.menu.dashboard' for component:  [class=org.apache.nutch.webui.pages.DashboardPage]. Locale: null, style: null
     at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:237)
     at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:130)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getString(Component.java:1843)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getString(Component.java:1830)
     at org.apache.nutch.webui.pages.AbstractBasePage.addMenuItem(AbstractBasePage.java:151)
     at org.apache.nutch.webui.pages.AbstractBasePage.(AbstractBasePage.java:77)
     at org.apache.nutch.webui.pages.DashboardPage.(DashboardPage.java:37)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:133)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:271)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:862)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:322)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)